# If comparison statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

This block of code returns "cat", "dog", "hamster", *and* "unicorn", but it shouldn't return "unicorn" at all! Is there any reason for this?

```
if random.randint(0,10) < 5:
    print("dog")    
elif  random.randint(0,10) > 5:
    print("cat")    
elif  random.randint(0,10) == 5:
    print("hamster")    
else:
    print("unicorn")
```

Comment: check your indention!

Comment: @DavidZwicker: I fixed the indentation, which was broken only due to SO formatting as far as I could tell.

Comment: It can happen. You use 3 different calls to the random function... This means, it can happen that first random call returns 6: so the first expression is false, the second is 4, so that's false too, and the third is not 5, and wow! Unicorn...

Comment: Why not `random.choice(("dog", "cat", "hamster"))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.randint` is called again each time it is reached, potentially producing a different result each time (since that is the function's purpose).

If you want to repeatedly test with the same value, then store the value first.

Comment: Thank you! I set it equal to a term and now it works fine, no unicorns show up at all.

Comment: @Ataulf: More then a thanks is an accepted answer appreciated! ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You're getting new random number on each comparison. What you probably meant is:

```
my_random_int = random.randint(0,10)

if my_random_int < 5:
    print("dog")

elif  my_random_int > 5:
    print("cat")

elif my_random_int == 5:
    print("hamster")

else:
    print("unicorn")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create the random number only once!

```
val = random.randint(0,10)
if val < 5:
    print("dog")

elif val > 5:
    print("cat")

elif val == 5:
    print("hamster")

else:
    print("unicorn")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming correct indentation, there's no reason for three random ints to be respectively `>=5`, `<=5`, and "not `5`".

You probably meant to do this:

```
value = random.randint(0, 10)

if value < 5:
    print("dog")
elif value > 5:
    print("cat")
elif value == 5:
    print("hamster")
else:
    print("unicorn")
```

Now there are no chances of unicorns.

Answer (score 1):

Your random number is different everytime you call `random.randint` so it might be 7 when you test the first if and go past it, then 3, then 4, and bam, you're in unicorn.

You should call `random.randint` only once at the beginning of your `if`, save its value and check it instead.

```
myrand = random.randint(0,10)
if myrand < 5:
  print("dog")    
elif myrand > 5:
  print("cat")    
elif myrand == 5:
  print("hamster")    
else:
  print("unicorn")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're generating a new random number each time. You should create it once and then assign it to a variable, then check that.

Answer (score 0):

You're generating three different random numbers. What you're thinking is this:

```
random_number = random.randint(0,10)

if random_number < 5:
    print("dog")

elif random_number > 5:
    print("cat")

elif random_number == 5:
    print("hamster")

else:
    print("unicorn")
```

This code will only return one word, and will never return "unicorn".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create only one random integer.

Your code should be:

```
myRandom = random.randint(0,10)

if myRandom < 5:
    print("dog")    
elif  myRandom > 5:
    print("cat")    
elif  myRandom == 5:
    print("hamster")    
else:
    print("unicorn")
```

Comment: What's the reason for >= and <= ? I don't grasp the problem. Furthermore the OP catched the result of ==5!

Comment: Then i suggest you adjust your answer, there are some trolls out there which would love to downvote your answer because of this! ;-)

Comment: That's not the issue at all, see above. 

Edit. Just saw that you got the second part. Suggest you delete the first sentence, that's not true at all. (Unless you don't like hamsters)